# How to completely remove renv from an R statistics program

Tags: r, packrat, renv

I have been using `renv` on a R project, but now want to remove it from renv versioning, i.e. delete all renv associated files, but still have access to the libraries that I used installed under renv. How do I do this? Alternatively, how do I migrate from renv to packrat?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

From RStudio's documentation, link provided by Kevin:

To deactivate `renv` in a project, use `renv::deactivate()`. This removes the `renv` auto-loader from the project `.Rprofile`, but doesn’t touch any other `renv` files used in the project. If you’d like to later re-activate `renv`, you can do so with `renv::activate()`.

To remove `renv` from a project, use `renv::deactivate()` to first remove the `renv` auto-loader from the project `.Rprofile`, then delete the project’s `renv` folder and `renv.lock` lockfile as desired.

If you want to completely remove any installed `renv` infrastructure components from your entire system, you can do so with the following R code:

```
root <- renv::paths$root()
unlink(root, recursive = TRUE)
```

The `renv` package can then also be uninstalled via:

```
utils::remove.packages("renv")
```

Note that if you’ve customized any of `renv`’s infrastructure paths as described in `?renv::paths`, then you’ll need to find and remove those customized folders as well.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried `renv::isolate`? That should bring over all the libraries from the renv shared cache into the local project directory?  But perhaps that's not what you want to do?

Comment: That that is part of the answer, but how do I also get rid of all the renv files in the project, switch any setting from renv back to standard, and turn off any process it may have started, i.e uninstall renv?